# How do account-settings works on Android Nougat?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-6.0-marshmallow, accountmanager, android-7.0-nougat

I implemented a simple app where, through AccountManager, it's possible to create a new user and going to "Settings-> Accounts" (from the system configuration) you can configure / delete a created account.

This is part of my **AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<service android:name="pratiche.auth.CustomAuthService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"
            android:resource="@xml/custom_authenticator" />
    </service>
    <activity android:name="pratiche.auth.SettingsActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**custom_authenticator.xml**

```
<account-authenticator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accountType="pratiche.android.account" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
     android:label="@string/custom_authenticator_label"
    android:accountPreferences="@xml/pref_general"/>
```

**pref_general.xml:**

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <SwitchPreference android:defaultValue="true" android:key="example_switch"
               android:summary="@string/pref_description_social_recommendations"
                android:title="@string/pref_title_social_recommendations" />
```

**SettingsActivity.java:**

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {


    /**
     * Helper method to determine if the device has an extra-large screen. For
     * example, 10" tablets are extra-large.
     */
    private static boolean isXLargeTablet(Context context) {
        return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
                & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE;
    }



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }



    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onIsMultiPane() {
        return isXLargeTablet(this);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public void onBuildHeaders(List<PreferenceActivity.Header> target) {
        loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.pref_headers, target);
    }

    /**
     * This method stops fragment injection in malicious applications.
     * Make sure to deny any unknown fragments here.
     */
    protected boolean isValidFragment(String fragmentName) {
        return PreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
                || GeneralPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName);

    }



    /**
     * This fragment shows general preferences only. It is used when the
     * activity is showing a two-pane settings UI.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public static class GeneralPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        }

        @Override
        public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == android.R.id.home) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class));
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }


}
```

**pref_headers.xml:**

```
<preference-headers xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <header
        android:fragment="pratiche.auth.SettingsActivity$GeneralPreferenceFragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_info_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/pref_header_general" />

</preference-headers>
```

**gradle configuration:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "pratiche"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:preference-v14:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

the problem is that the same code executed on Nexus 5x with Android Marshmallow (6+) works properly:
[created account,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqMmI.png) [account settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kmamj.png)

Instead run on Nexus 5x with Android Nougat (7+) does not work and returns the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.android.settings/com.android.settings.SubSettings}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class (not found)SwitchPreference
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3400)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3440)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2713)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                                                Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class (not found)SwitchPreference
                                                   at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceInflater.createItemFromTag(PreferenceInflater.java:301)
                                                   at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceInflater.rInflate(PreferenceInflater.java:359)
                                                   at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceInflater.inflate(PreferenceInflater.java:167)
                                                   at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceInflater.inflate(PreferenceInflater.java:117)
                                                   at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceManager.inflateFromResource(PreferenceManager.java:122)
                                                   at com.android.settings.accounts.AccountPreferenceBase.addPreferencesForType(AccountPreferenceBase.java:161)
                                                   at com.android.settings.accounts.ManageAccountsSettings.addPreferencesForType(ManageAccountsSettings.java)
                                                   at com.android.settings.accounts.ManageAccountsSettings.addAuthenticatorSettings(ManageAccountsSettings.java:406)
                                                   at com.android.settings.accounts.ManageAccountsSettings.showAccountsIfNeeded(ManageAccountsSettings.java:398)
                                                   at com.android.settings.accounts.ManageAccountsSettings.onResume(ManageAccountsSettings.java:112)
                                                   at android.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:2398)
                                                   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1032)
                                                   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1171)
                                                   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1153)
                                                   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchResume(FragmentManager.java:2049)
                                                   at android.app.FragmentController.dispatchResume(FragmentController.java:198)
                                                   at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6789)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3377)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3440) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2713) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
                                                Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.preference.SwitchPreference" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/priv-app/CellBroadcastReceiver/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
                                                   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
                                                   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                                                   at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceInflater.createItem(PreferenceInflater.java:233)
                                                   at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceInflater.onCreateItem(PreferenceInflater.java:281)
                                                   at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceInflater.createItemFromTag(PreferenceInflater.java:290)
                                                   at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceInflater.rInflate(PreferenceInflater.java:359) 
                                                   at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceInflater.inflate(PreferenceInflater.java:167) 
                                                   at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceInflater.inflate(PreferenceInflater.java:117) 
                                                   at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceManager.inflateFromResource(PreferenceManager.java:122) 
                                                   at com.android.settings.accounts.AccountPreferenceBase.addPreferencesForType(AccountPreferenceBase.java:161) 
                                                   at com.android.settings.accounts.ManageAccountsSettings.addPreferencesForType(ManageAccountsSettings.java) 
                                                   at com.android.settings.accounts.ManageAccountsSettings.addAuthenticatorSettings(ManageAccountsSettings.java:406) 
                                                   at com.android.settings.accounts.ManageAccountsSettings.showAccountsIfNeeded(ManageAccountsSettings.java:398) 
                                                   at com.android.settings.accounts.ManageAccountsSettings.onResume(ManageAccountsSettings.java:112) 
                                                   at android.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:2398) 
                                                   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1032) 
                                                   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1171) 
                                                   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1153) 
                                                   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchResume(FragmentManager.java:2049) 
                                                   at android.app.FragmentController.dispatchResume(FragmentController.java:198) 
                                                   at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6789) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3377) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3440) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2713) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: That crash seems to be from the Settings app, not yours.